# Writing a program that can authenticate with gitlab cloud and get a list of all git project urls in a group

Tags: gitlab

I want to write a c++ program that can automatically handle my git repos that I have created inside a private group folder in my gitlab cloud account.

What I want to be able to do is get a list of all git projects with their respective URLs inside a private group folder. As it's private i guess I will need to get the program to authenticate with the gitlab cloud server using a user account that I create that has rights to view the group.

What is the best way to go about achieving this? I know there is an API but it seems to be for the Enterprise Edition and not the cloud.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by cloud? Are you referring to `gitlab.com`? If that's the case then you can use the API for that (I believe it's available on all versions of Gitlab)

Comment: Yes i mean gitlab.com but it looks like the API is only available for community edition and enterprise edition.

Comment: Gitlab.com runs enterprise edition

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely use the API with gitlab.com as it runs Gitlab Enterprise Edition.

First go to https://gitlab.com/profile/personal_access_tokens with a logged in user in order to create your API access token.

Once you have that access token, you'll be able to make calls to the API. Here are a few pointers for groups and projects endpoints: [list projects within group](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/groups.html#list-a-group-39-s-projects), [projects](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html), [basic usage](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/README.html#basic-usage)